# RTCSessionDescription and video/audio broadcast

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Once I have exchanged session description between two peers. How can I allow the user to prevent audio and/or video broadcast? Do I need to exchange the Session Descriptions again?

Comment: You mean once the P2P RTC connection is established?

Comment: Yes, the connection is established. Now, one client wants to disable his (video and/or audio) stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Broadcast" is probably not the correct term since PeerConnections are always unicast peer-to-peer.
2. To acquire an audio/video stream from the user's devices you call getUserMedia() and to send these to the other peer you call addStream() on the PeerConnection object.

So to allow the user to **not** send the acquired stream just let her choose whether to call addStream() or not. E.g. show a popup saying "Send Audio/Video to the other user?". If she chooses "Yes" call addStream() on the PeerConnection object, otherwise just don't call it.

**EDIT to answer question in comment**:

If you'd like to stop sending of audio and/or video just call removeStream() on the PeerConnection object with the stream to remove as parameter. This will per the API spec trigger a renegotiation.

See http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#interface-definition for further details.

Comment: Thanks, you are right Broadcast isn't the right term. 
Lets say initially both users share both audio/video streams (and they are connected), now one client wants to disable his audio/video stream and just see the remote user stream. Do I need to exchange Session Descriptions again?